# Multidimensional array values with RecursiveArrayIterator for select option groups

Tags: php, arrays

I have this new multidimensional array and I'm trying to make multiple drop-down selects with option groups. So that each select contains options with `"$value[ 'proj_id' ]` `$value[ 'projName' ]`. Selects are grouped by ID (the first select: 127, second select: 131, third select: 130 etc.) Options are grouped by clients names, first opt.group *Another client*, with one option. Second opt. group *Nice* with two options etc. Before I was using `RecursiveArrayIterator()` now with third dimension it no longer works:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator( $project_data_group );
$dropdown = '';
// get  all children for dropdown
while ( $iterator->valid() ) {
    if ( $iterator->hasChildren() ) {
        foreach ( $iterator->getChildren() as $key1 => $value ) {
           $dropdown .= "<option data-proj_id=" . $value[ 'proj_id' ] . " value=" . $value[ 'projName' ] . ">" . $value[ 'projName' ] . "</option>";

        }
    }
    break;
}
```

```
array (
  127 => 
  array (
    'Another client' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-04 09:33:00',
        'id' => '127',
        'cID' => '50',
        'client' => 'Another client',
        'proj_id' => '103',
        'projName' => 'Logo new',
        'is_from_main_table' => '1',
      ),
    ),
    'Nice' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-04 09:33:00',
        'id' => '127',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '106',
        'projName' => 'Advert',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-04 09:33:00',
        'id' => '127',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '102',
        'projName' => 'Webpage',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Mikrosoft' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-04 09:33:00',
        'id' => '127',
        'cID' => '51',
        'client' => 'Mikrosoft',
        'proj_id' => '104',
        'projName' => 'Poster',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Gooble' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-04 09:33:00',
        'id' => '127',
        'cID' => '48',
        'client' => 'Gooble',
        'proj_id' => '105',
        'projName' => 'Poster another',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  131 => 
  array (
    'Nice' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-08 17:23:00',
        'id' => '131',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '102',
        'projName' => 'Webpage',
        'is_from_main_table' => '1',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-08 17:23:00',
        'id' => '131',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '106',
        'projName' => 'Advert',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Another client' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-08 17:23:00',
        'id' => '131',
        'cID' => '50',
        'client' => 'Another client',
        'proj_id' => '103',
        'projName' => 'Logo new',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Mikrosoft' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-08 17:23:00',
        'id' => '131',
        'cID' => '51',
        'client' => 'Mikrosoft',
        'proj_id' => '104',
        'projName' => 'Poster',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Gooble' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-08 17:23:00',
        'id' => '131',
        'cID' => '48',
        'client' => 'Gooble',
        'proj_id' => '105',
        'projName' => 'Poster another',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  130 => 
  array (
    'Gooble' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-09 17:30:00',
        'id' => '130',
        'cID' => '48',
        'client' => 'Gooble',
        'proj_id' => '105',
        'projName' => 'Poster another',
        'is_from_main_table' => '1',
      ),
    ),
    'Nice' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-09 17:30:00',
        'id' => '130',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '106',
        'projName' => 'Advert',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-09 17:30:00',
        'id' => '130',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '102',
        'projName' => 'Webpage',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Another client' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-09 17:30:00',
        'id' => '130',
        'cID' => '50',
        'client' => 'Another client',
        'proj_id' => '103',
        'projName' => 'Logo new',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Mikrosoft' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-09 17:30:00',
        'id' => '130',
        'cID' => '51',
        'client' => 'Mikrosoft',
        'proj_id' => '104',
        'projName' => 'Poster',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  133 => 
  array (
    'Nice' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-11 19:58:00',
        'id' => '133',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '106',
        'projName' => 'Advert',
        'is_from_main_table' => '1',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-11 19:58:00',
        'id' => '133',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '102',
        'projName' => 'Webpage',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Another client' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-11 19:58:00',
        'id' => '133',
        'cID' => '50',
        'client' => 'Another client',
        'proj_id' => '103',
        'projName' => 'Logo new',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Mikrosoft' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-11 19:58:00',
        'id' => '133',
        'cID' => '51',
        'client' => 'Mikrosoft',
        'proj_id' => '104',
        'projName' => 'Poster',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Gooble' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-11 19:58:00',
        'id' => '133',
        'cID' => '48',
        'client' => 'Gooble',
        'proj_id' => '105',
        'projName' => 'Poster another',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  134 => 
  array (
    'Mikrosoft' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-22 13:36:00',
        'id' => '134',
        'cID' => '51',
        'client' => 'Mikrosoft',
        'proj_id' => '104',
        'projName' => 'Poster',
        'is_from_main_table' => '1',
      ),
    ),
    'Nice' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-22 13:36:00',
        'id' => '134',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '106',
        'projName' => 'Advert',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-22 13:36:00',
        'id' => '134',
        'cID' => '47',
        'client' => 'Nice',
        'proj_id' => '102',
        'projName' => 'Webpage',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Another client' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-22 13:36:00',
        'id' => '134',
        'cID' => '50',
        'client' => 'Another client',
        'proj_id' => '103',
        'projName' => 'Logo new',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'Gooble' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'dateTime' => '2020-06-22 13:36:00',
        'id' => '134',
        'cID' => '48',
        'client' => 'Gooble',
        'proj_id' => '105',
        'projName' => 'Poster another',
        'is_from_main_table' => '0',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: When you say you want Option Groups, do you mean you want `<optgroup>` for each 127 and 131 etc

Comment: Can you show your array as a `var_export()` that output we can easily use to test an answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited array to `var_export()`. Yes I want `<optgroup>` but for each  Another client and Nice and  Mikrosoft etc. I need five selects, each contains one array: 127, 131, 130, 133, 134 with grouped options.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but based on the grouping you want, this approach might work.

```
function getGroupedDropdownOptions($array) {
    $options = [];
    foreach ( $array as $groups ) {
        foreach ( $groups as $clientName => $group ) {
            // You should be able to use $clientName or $group['client'] here
            $options[$group['client']][] = ["proj_name" => $group['projName'],  "proj_id" => $group['proj_id'];
        }
        break;
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Build the HTML like this after setting $dropdownOptions with getGroupedDropdownOptions().

```
<select>
    <?php foreach($dropdownOptions as $groupName => $group): ?>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo $groupName; ?>">
            <?php foreach($group as $option): ?>
                <option data-proj_id="<?php echo $option['proj_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $option['proj_name']; ?>"> <?php echo $option['proj_name']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </optgroup>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: In the code I gave, I don't use array keys of the second level (ie: "Another client", "Nice", etc). But I want to use them as `<optgroup> ` First level keys make multiple (five in total) selects  127, 131, 130, 133, 134 with grouped options.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow. If that data is in `client`, why not use that?

Comment: yes, that is `client`. I could, but don't know how. Idea was to use that to make group array, and them from that I could make `<optgroup>`

Comment: @Atis I updated the answer to just use foreach loops. This should build the data the way you need it, but I haven't tested it.